# CSS selector for "having previous sibling of"

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an element with a `ng-list` attribute. The very next sibling to this element is an `<ol>`. I want to write a CSS selector that selects this `<ol>`.

In other words, I want to write CSS that applies to an `<ol>` when the `<ol>` has an immediate previous sibling of `[ng-list]`.

Possible?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1817792/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS doesn't have a 'previous element' selector yet.

Since you want to select the `ol` that immediately follows another element, use `+`, it will select only the specified element that immediately follows the former specified element.

In your case

```
[ng-list] + ol {
    /* css rules */
}
```

Ref: [5.7 Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Answer (score 4):

It's called an [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

For starters, I would never ever write this CSS selector, you're tying to an angular attribute, it makes no sense. You should just give you OL a class.

```
[ng-list] + ol { /* rules here */ }
```